# LED lights switch off every 30 seconds

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, led

So recently I have purchased a set of LED fairy lights. As soon as I turned them on without even putting them up, the lights would only turn on for 30 seconds. For example, I pressed the colour blue on the remote provided, and it would light up perfectly for 30 seconds, but then completely turn off. After 3-5 seconds they turn back on. Does anyone know how to fix this problem or have any suggestions, so I can have the lights on a colour for a longer period of time?

Comment: Have you thoroughly read and followed the direction for any programming  of the driver?

Comment: It says on the instructions : 'setting the timer program when you want it to light up automatically at the same time every day (optional)' and then it says 'pre-programmed timing sequence of 6 hours ON and 18 hours OFF over each 24 hour period'. Do you know how I would do this?

Comment: Are they solar or battery powered? If so, sounds like a depleted battery. If not, I'd say they are defective and return them. I know the kind of remote you are talking about and it doesn't have a "30 seconds off function"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about small appliance operation, and so off-topic.

Comment: If a brand new product doesn't work, contact the vendor or manufacturer for instructions and/or a refund.